# Getting a 100% height/width border on main div(or body)

Tags: html, css

http://designobvio.us/vodka/ Live demo

I've set my html, container, main and 100% but nomatter what I do I cannot get the border to be 100% height without scroll bars?

How can I achieve an effect?

HTML

```
  <div id="main">

  </div>
```

CSS (not currently the live code but this is what i've tried )

```
html, body{height:100%; width:100%;} 
#main{height:100%; position:absolute; top:0px; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px; border:5px solid #000;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a fixed border or dynamic border? The problem with your code is the W3C box-model. In the default model, padding, margin and border are added to the size of your element. So in your code what you're really telling it is "make the box 100% and then add 10px worth of border".

Normally an easy change would be to manually switch the box model, but unfortunately that property does not play nice with `height: 100%`. So you have a few options:

1) If you are looking for a fixed border, this is a good trick: http://css-tricks.com/body-border/
2) If you need a dynamic border, you need to somehow get around the additional height the border adds. Here is one way:

```
html,body { height:100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#container {
    min-height:100%;
    border-right: 5px solid #000;
    border-left: 5px solid #000;
    position: relative; /* relative postion so we can absolutely position footer within it */
}
#header {
    height: 100px;
    border-top: 5px solid #000;
    background-color: red;
}
#content { padding: 0 0 100px 0; } /*padding must be equal to the height of the footer*/
#footer {
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%; /* with absolute position, a width must be declared */
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Qw2cb/

Answer (score 2):

By default the borders, margin and padding are not part of width/height and are added on top. That's why you get scrollbars as the full dimensions of the box are 100% in height and width plus the border-width.

You can set the `box-sizing` property to `border-box`, which tells the browser to include the calculation for borders and padding in the width/height properties (in opposite to `content-box`, which is the default value):

```
#main {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    [...]      
}
```

As especially IE8 and the earlier version of the other browser families don't support this css-property, it's a good idea to add some browser-specific definitions, too:

```
#main {
   -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -ms-box-sizing:     border-box;
    box-sizing:        border-box;
}
```

Take a look at the [mozilla doku for detailed information on box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but as it pops up on Google first page... Here is my solution that seems to work fine cross browsers:

```
height: 0:
border-style: solid;
border-width: 8vw 0 0 100vw;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent red;
```

Just used it for an :after pseudo-element in order to turn it in a triangle shape and it works just fine (test down to ie10).

Simply use `100vw` instead of `100%` and it should do the trick.

Comment: Indeed I know. Thought that would be helpful to someone else maybe!

Answer (score 1):

You can give `box-size:border-box;` to 'main', like

```
#main{
    box-size:border-box;
}
```

Doing so the border will be added to 100% height of main. [Learn more about box sizing here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

Answer (score 0):

So, you are saying that you do not want to display scrollbars?

CSS:

```
#main
{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
}
```